# I can't chattr to /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

I can't change use chattr here. It's not a symbolic link. Why can't I change the attribute?

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf
brunot@W000000DRKPLN3:~$ ls /etc/resolv.conf
/etc/resolv.conf
brunot@W000000DRKPLN3:~$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 266 Jan 31 14:22 /etc/resolv.conf
brunot@W000000DRKPLN3:~$
```